# How to input and output A Object data in Android Jetpack Workmanger?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager, workmanagers

In Android Jetpack WorkManger, define a output data in Worker:

```
new Data.Builder().putLong(xxx);
```

there are `putLong, putString, putBoolean`, BUT there are not define a function to put a `Object`.

How can i output `a Entity Object` in Worker.

```
public class DownloadDB extends Worker {
    private static final String TAG = "DownloadDB";
    private List<ChoiceTestItem> mChoiceTestItems;

    public DownloadDB(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        downChoiceTestItemFromNetwork();
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        //Wrong Code here!!!
        map.put("a", mChoiceTestItems);
        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi") Data data = new Data.Builder().putAll(map).build();

        return Result.success(data);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there are not define a function to put a Object.

Correct. You cannot put arbitrary objects into a `Data`. As [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/Data) states: "This is a lightweight container, and should not be considered your data store". Not allowing arbitrary data types is one way they are enforcing this.

> How can i output a Entity Object in Worker.

If by "Entity Object" you mean a Room `@Entity`, put the entity in your database. Put the primary key or other identifier into the `Data`, and use that to retrieve the entity at a later point from the database.

Comment: 1. This is a lightweight container, and should not be considered your data store
2.  put the entity in your database 
Thanks.